# Different new based on condition

Tags: perl

I have this Perl code:

```
my $C;

if($someCondition) {
    my $A = My::Package::A::V1->new();
    my $B = My::Package::B::V1->new();
    $C = My::Package::C::V1->new();
} else {
    my $A = My::Package::A::V2->new();
    my $B = My::Package::B::V2->new();
    $C = My::Package::C::V2->new();
}
# Have fun with $C
```

I find this very redundant, considering that the only difference is `V1` or `V2` based on `$someCondition`. Is there any way to do something like `my $A = My::Package::A::V{$someCondition ? 1 : 2}->new();`?

---

What if I have also:

```
my $C;
if($someCondition) {
    my $C = Some::Package::Z->new(
      myPackageA => &My::Package::A::V1
    );
} else {
    my $C = Some::Package::Z->new(
      myPackageA => &My::Package::A::V2
    );
}
```

For this one I tried:

```
my $api_version;
if($someCondition) {
    $api_version = 'V1';
} else {
    $api_version = 'V2';
}
my $C = Some::Package::Z->new(
    myPackageA => "&My::Package::A::$api_version"
);
```

But I get the error: `Can't call method new on an undefined value`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store the class in a string and use it to reference the package:

```
my $api_version;
if($someCondition) {
    $api_version = 'V1';
} else {
    $api_version = 'V2';
}
die "No API version found" unless $api_version;

my $A = "My::Package::A::$api_version"->new();
my $B = "My::Package::B::$api_version"->new();
my $C = "My::Package::C::$api_version"->new();

# Have fun with $C
```

If you also want to call functions in the namespaces (as you do with your expanded question), the easy approach is to switch off `strict` and just call the functions using their name:

```
my $make_A;
{
    no strict 'refs';
    $make_A = \&{ "My::Package::A::$api_version" };
}
my $C = Some::Package::Z->new(
  myPackageA => $make_A->(),
);
```

Comment: Thanks, good idea! Could you please give a look at the updated question?

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do there. What is the string `&My::Package::A::V1` supposed to be? How is `Some::Package::Z` different from `My::Package::Z` ?

Comment: Another option for functions that doesn't require turning off strict: `my $subref = "My::Package::A"->can($api_version)`